# Java - best way to deal with a large GUI constructor?

Tags: java, user-interface, constructor

I find that when making gui application in Java, the constructor of my GUI class becomes very long if i dont abstract/extract it away to other classes or methods to shorten it... What is the best/most logical/least messy way of dealing with a large gui constructor? I have gathered two of the most common ways i use to deal with this... What would be the best approach, and more importantly, why/why not?

Method 1, organizing into classes for each gui component, where each class extends its GUI component:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
public GUI(String title){
    super(title);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.add(new mainPanel());
}
private class mainPanel extends JPanel{
    private mainPanel(){
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new PlayButton("Play Now"));
    }
    private class PlayButton extends JButton{
        private PlayButton(String text){
            this.setText(text);
            this.setSize(150,50);
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Method 2: using initialization methods, and methods that return instances of each gui component:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
public GUI(String title){
    super(title);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    initGuiComponents();
}

private void initGuiComponents(){
    this.add(mainPanel());
}
private JPanel mainPanel(){
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(playButton("Play Now"));
    return mainPanel;
}

private JButton playButton(String text){
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setText(text);
button.setSize(150,50);
button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
return button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using combination of both would be a good idea.

Instead of using inner classes, having top level classes might make the code more maintainable. You could divide the frame into small panels based on functionality and responsibility. If your segregation is good enough, they will be loosely coupled and you would not need to pass many arguments to them.

At the same time, if the constructor or any method is growing out of proportions, clubbing tightly related operations into private methods might be helpful to make the code readable.

---

Beautiful programs result from high quality abstraction and encapsulation.

Even though achieving those needs practice and experience, sticking to [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) should always be your first priority.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into using the [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html?null).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same settings on many components (i.e. every Button has the same BG/FG color), use a factory:

```
class ComponentFactory{
    static JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Then, in your constructors, you can adjust the non-constant settings:

```
JButton button = ComponentFactory.createButton();
button.setText(text);
[...]
```

The advantage with this is that you only need to change a setting (like BG color) once to change the look of all buttons.

For keeping the constructors short, I usually split the process to `createChildren()`, `layoutComponents()`, `registerListeners()` and whatever else might seem useful. I then call these methods from a constructor in an abstract superclass. As a result, many subclasses don't require a constructor at all - or a really short one calling `super()` and doing some custom settings.